# Why does the fragment manager return null here?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Why does the log-line yield "true" here? I just added a fragment with tag "ID"!

```
FragmentTransaction ftrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ftrans.add(0, new MyFrag(), "ID");
ftrans.commit();
Fragment frag =  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ID");
Log.i("", "Fragment is null? " + (frag == null));
```

Is there a delay on the commit? If so, is there any event I can listen for when the commit is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `public abstract int commit ()`
>
> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen
> immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be
> done the next time that thread is ready.

You can try adding  fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() after your commit() and before finding your tag.